# Intellij IDEA : Spark code running results in java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

In IntelliJ IDEA, I am trying to execute a Java file with spark code - which results in java.lang.VerifyError.

StackTrace is as follows:

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
>   java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering,
>   method: tryCompare signature:
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type
>   in function   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)

My understanding of the error - there is some version conflict with Scala versions in client scala (IntelliJ) and scala version of Spark 1.6.1.

The same code was working fine the day before, but now gives the above error.

Surprisingly, the same code executes fine on Eclipse.

Full stack trace :

```
16/08/20 22:25:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/20 22:25:39 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/20 22:25:39 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/20 22:25:39 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: [Container in shutdown] Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/08/20 22:25:39 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/08/20 22:25:39 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) on executor localhost: java.lang.VerifyError ((class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function) [duplicate 1]
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 1 (map at LinearRegression.scala:161) failed in 0.406 s
16/08/20 22:25:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: first at LinearRegression.scala:163, took 0.437687 s

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1342)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1341)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.train(LinearRegression.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
    at com.datarpm.insights.ensemble.scorer.PipelineEnsembleScorerTest.regressionTests(PipelineEnsembleScorerTest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificOrdering, method: tryCompare signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Some;) Wrong return type in function
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateOrdering$.create(GenerateOrdering.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator.generate(CodeGenerator.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.newOrdering(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This issue was caused due to in-correct version of spark library (2.11), identified by analyzing Maven dependency tree. However, unable to identify why it was working fine in Eclipse while failing IntelliJ

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same exception, but I have spark 2.0 with scala 2.11.8. Could you please provide your pom file with correctly working documentation?

Comment: Make sure all your dependency jars are compiled with 2.11.8 and re-import module into IntelliJ.  
I have cleared M2 local repository also, but it' may not be needed.

Comment: My problem was that I have: cascading : cascading-core : 2.6.1 in my classpath. Also I had org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had almost the same problem. Root cause was that cascading and spark-catalyst both have ***org.codehaus.janino*** dependecy. As a result spark used unexpected janino lib version
Pleese see *mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose* command output

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.7.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.7.5)    
[INFO] +- cascading:cascading-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- cascading:cascading-core:jar:tests:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was with conflicting jars.
I had a internal project's dependency jar compile with older Scala version  2.11.4. But Spark was compiled with 2.11.8.

By re-compiling all dependent jars to use same Java and Scala target versions resolved my problem.